# why mysql row_id takes 6 bytes

Tags: mysql

The internal 6-byte id for InnoDB exists only if you don't have either

- An explicit PRIMARY KEY, or
- A UNIQUE with non-null column(s).

why mysql row_id takes 6 bytes, instead of 8 Bytes?

Comment: Why exactly do you think it should be 8?

Comment: Any reason you need more than 281 trillion (2^48, from 6 bytes * 8 bit) rows?

Comment: The developers assumed that by the time the number of records in the table reaches 256kkkk, the programmer will understand that he needs a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Because the developers felt like it.  Kidding aside,...

Meanwhile, it allocates values in chunks of 256, so there can be random gaps.

That gives you at least a trillion rows.

Anyway, a non-partitioned InnoDB table is limited to 64TB for other reasons.  (Or perhaps only 32TB, I am not sure).

I'm pretty sure the choice of 6 bytes was made before Partitioning was added, possibly before the year 2000.